# Sweetalert2 scrollbar in the background

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

Im trying to use [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) in my Angular app and its working but everytime a swal popup opens there is a scrollbar in the background and everything below the scrollbar is just white...
[image: sweetalert2 Popup with scrollbar in the background]

```
const swal = require('sweetalert2');
    swal({
      title: 'Sind Sie sicher?',
      text: "Sie werden möglicherweise Gebühren für die vorzeitige Kündigung zahlen müssen!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      cancelButtonText:'Abbrechen',
      confirmButtonText: 'Ja'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {.....}
```

Its only working with that first line... If i Import swal from sweetalert2 it just doesnt open anything...

Comment: Hi I'm the author of sweetalert2 and I'll be happy to help you if you could provide a jsfiddle with your case, jsfiddle template: https://jsfiddle.net/ad3quksn/462/

Comment: I fixed it already. Sweetalert2 wasnt the problem.